# Law of Large Number for Stochastic Processes

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Consider the following Stochastic Process:

$$B(t)∼N(μt,σt)$$

Here is a simulation for multiple possible trajectories of this Stochastic Process (R Code):

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

## Helper function to make the initial increment to be 0
first_to_zero <- function(v) {
    v[1] <- 0
    v
}

n_sep <- 101
n_iter <- 1000
time_length <- 10
mu <- 0.5  # Define the drift term

data2 <- data.frame(id  = rep(seq_len(n_iter), each = n_sep),
                    x   = rep(seq(from = 0, to = time_length, length.out = n_sep), n_iter),
                    z = rnorm(n = n_sep * n_iter, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(time_length / n_sep))) %>%  # Change the standard deviation to sqrt(time_length / n_sep)
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(z = first_to_zero(z),
           y   = mu * x + cumsum(z))  # Add the drift 

ggplot(data = data2, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, group = id)) +
    geom_line(alpha = 1 / (n_iter / 100)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, time_length, by = 0.5)) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = seq(0, time_length, by = 0.5), linetype="dotted", color = "red", alpha = 2) +  
    theme_bw() + theme(legend.key = element_blank())
```

Suppose we are interested in estimating the parameters of this Stochastic Process (i.e. $σ$
and $μ$) based on a single trajectory of this Stochastic Process (i.e. via Maximum Likelihood Estimation).

**My Question:**

- The more we observe this process (i.e. for larger values of $t$) - will our estimates for $σ$ and $μ$ improve as $t$ gets larger? In other words (note that the MLE estimators are functions of $n$, i.e. $t$)  does it mean that

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} P\left( \left| \mu - \hat{\mu}_{MLE} \right| > \epsilon \right) = 0$$
$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} P\left( \left| \sigma - \hat{\sigma}_{MLE} \right| > \epsilon \right) = 0$$

- If I (whimsically and) incorrectly treated this Stochastic Process as i.i.d Gaussian - I wonder if it is possible to compare the estimates calculated using a likelihood function based on the Stochastic Process vs the estimates calculated from the (incorrect) likelihood function based on a Normal Distribution? Can the maximum error be bounded?

At first I thought the answer is not certain (i.e. longer observation periods might not necessarily always result in better estimation) because the Stochastic Process has non-constant and non-finite variance, thus invalidating the Law of Large Numbers and Central Limit Theorem ... but then I thought that perhaps the Stochastic Process can be re-parametrized (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem) in terms of the Weiner Process (independent Gaussian increments), and thus the Law or Large Numbers would apply, suggesting that larger observation periods would bring parameter estimates closer to their actual values (in probability).

I think a similar argument is true for Central Limit Theorem, i.e. for larger values of $t$ (i.e.$n$), the sampling distribution of the MLE estimates approach a standard Normal Distribution? (I think this is incorrect because there are many versions of the CLT which might be better suited for this situation e.g. CLT based on Martingales)

$$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\mu}_{MLE} - \mu) \xrightarrow{d} N(0, \sigma^2)$$
$$n(\hat{\sigma}^2_{MLE} - \sigma^2) \xrightarrow{d} \chi^2(n-1)$$

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!

Sources:

- https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/brownian-linear-spline

Comment: It's an interesting question and I have no idea what the answer is. You may want to look at the book by Stefano Iacus. ( I'll find it in a moment ). it discusses the estimation of stochastic differential equation parameters ( he refers to them as diffusion processes ). I have never read it but Stefano has quite a reputation so, if you can get your hands on it, I would take a look at that book. I unfortunately have it in storage. I'll send the link in a follow up comment.

Comment: @ mark leeds: thank you so much for your reply!

Comment: Here's the book I was referring to. He's written others since but I would take a look at this one first, if possible. https://www.amazon.com/Simulation-Inference-Stochastic-Differential-Equations/dp/0387758380/ref=sr_1_1?crid=12OHSDCG74SN&keywords=stefano+iacus&qid=1704946672&sprefix=stefano+iacus%2Caps%2C101&sr=8-1&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.f5122f16-c3e8-4386-bf32-63e904010ad0

Comment: You're welcome. I hope that you can find it ( a free version  possibly? ) and it atleast gets you started. And I made a mistake: He does refer to them as stochastic differential equations and not diffusion processes.

Comment: Thsnk you! I wonder why this question was down voted?

Comment: I wish someone could give me feedback as to how I can improve this question to avoid downvotes

Comment: I don't know ? I liked it. Maybe because the question isn't in the title ?

Comment: Thank you so much! I am learning about the differences between the weak markov property and the strong markov property.. if you have time, can you please take a look at this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4843798/understanding-the-strength-of-the-markov-property thank you so much!

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but personally I find it hard to understand what you're asking for : you want to know if the estimators "improve" as $t$ gets larger, but you didn't even define what estimators you're using (presumably they would depend on $t$). (I think it's possible to guess from reading the question in more detail, but it's not clear at all). Also, it seems that you're asking multiple questions. Try to keep it more focused. Lastly, in my opinion, the code and plot of the stochastic process is distracting from the question and could be omitted.

Comment: @ Stratos supports the strike: thank you for your reply. I thought the code/plot would help to illustrate the idea better ... i.e. the longer you observe the process (i.e. further down the x-axis), do you gain more meaningful information about the process itself?

Comment: I read your comments and feedback - thank you. I will make some changes based on them.

Comment: @stats_noob: I'm looking for a good explanation.  Definitely old threads here help  but I'm trying to find the best and clearest explanation. Note that it's really not helpful to compare the strong markov property with the weak markov property. I would think of the weak markov property as just the markov property and the strong markov property as the "stopping time" property because they really aren't related. Markov property says  that the probability of next state only depends on the state one is in. The stopping time property is much stronger and is only relevant for continuous time.

Comment: I'll get back to you with the best thing I find. I don't think me trying to explain it myself would be very helpful to you. I may provide a text, a paper or an example. I'm not sure yet.

Comment: You understand the "weak" markov property, right ? That's just the markov property which says that probabilities of going to a state and are only dependent on the current state one is in and not the previous states one was in before that. I just want to make sure that I know what you follow so that I send something helpful.

Comment: The question is extremely vague. Giving marginal distributions 
$B(t)∼N(μt,σt)$ do not give the distribution of the stochastic process. The simulations suggest that the process is $\sigma$ times a standard Brownian motion, with an additional drift $\mu$. If you assume that, write it explicitly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the assumptions are not fully clear, **I address the OP for some different cases**:

### **Case 1:** $B(t)$ **independent** for all $t$ and $B(t)∼N(μt,σ^2t^2)$

The answer is **yes** based on **a single trajectory** one can accurately estimates the parameters. If the index set is **countable**, having the trajectory for a longer period is helpful; otherwise; having it over a small interval is enough.

Let a single trajectory of $B(t)∼N(μt,σ^2t^2)$ be given at time instants $t=1, ..., T$, denoted by $B_1,..., B_T$. Then, you can use $B_1/1,...,B_T/T$ as a simple random sample from $N(μ,σ^2)$, which are iid, with sample size $T$. Then, you can use standard methods available for point or interval estimation of $μ$ and $σ$. Indeed, here, as $T$ increases, the accuracy level increases.

However, if the index set is a **continuum**, from a single trajectory over any **small** interval, you can accurately determine the parameters (almost surely) because you can take a sample of size infinity from the trajectory (**Remark**: this case is  of interest only in thorey, as a trajectory cannot be given for any $t\in[0,1]$ in practice).

### **Case 2:** $B(t)$ **independent** for all $t$ and $B(t)∼N(μt,σ^2t)$

In this case, one can use $X_1=B_1/1,...,X_T=B_T/T$ as independent RVs whose distributions are $X_i=N(μ,\frac{σ^2}{i}), i=1,...,T$, respectively. Here, the ML method can be used for the following non-standard likelihood function:

$$ l(\mu,\sigma^2)= \prod_{i=1}^{T} \frac{1}{  \sqrt{2 \pi \frac{\sigma^2}{i}} } \exp \left[ \frac{(x-\mu)^2}{-2\frac{\sigma^2}{i}} \right].$$

### **Case 3:** $B(t)∼N(μt,σ^2t^2)$ is a **continuous** Gaussian process

If $B(t)∼N(μt,σ^2t^2)$ is a **continuous** Gaussian process, it is **impossible** to accurately estimate the parameters based on a single trajectory of the process. Note that $B(t)$ has the following linear kernel:

$$C(s,t)=ts\sigma^2.$$

This means that for all $t$,

$$B(t)=tZ$$

where $Z$ follows the normal distribution $N(μ,σ^2)$. In fact, for any $t \neq s$ the correlation of $B(t)$ and $B(s)$ is 1 . Hence, all points on a single trajectory are linearly generated based  a unique observation from $N(μ,σ^2)$.

### **Case 4:** $B(t)∼N(μt,σ^2t)$ is a **continuous** Gaussian process

If $B(t)∼N(μt,σ^2t)$ is a **continuous** Gaussian process, it is **possible** to accurately estimate the parameters based on a single trajectory of the process. In this case, we have the following representation:

$$B(t)=t\mu+ \sigma W(t)$$

where $W(t)$ denotes the Wiener process. The kernel $C(s,t)$ of $B(t)$ is given by

$$C(s,t)=\min\{t,s\}\sigma^2,$$

which implies that non-overlapping increments of $B(t)$ are **independent** (because their covariances are zero). Then, considering $$\Delta B(t)=B(t+\Delta t)-B(t)∼N(μ\Delta t,σ^2\Delta t)$$ by equally discretizing an interval and computing the increments we can generate a simple random sample (of any size) from $N(μ\Delta t,σ^2\Delta t)$.

Comment: You assume that the $B_t$ are independent. This assumption was not given in the OP, and the conclusion would be false under those assumptions. Actually assumptions are missing in the OP. The simulations above suggest that the sample paths are continuous and the INCREMENTS are independent

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thanks for the feedback! The simulation is based on the independent case as I see. I added some comments on how a similar method can be applied for the processes with independent and weakly dependent increments.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the process considered is given by $B_t = \sigma W_t + \mu t$ where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion, and assume that you observe $B_0=0$ and $B_{k\Delta t}$ for $1 \le k \le n$. Then the increments $B_{(k+1)\Delta t}-B_{k\Delta t}$ are i.i.d. with distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu\Delta t,\sigma^2\Delta t)$. So you are led to the estimation of both parameters of a $n$-sample of a normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}$.