# Understanding the "Strength" of the Markov Property

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand why we say that the Strong Markov Property is indeed "stronger" than the Weak Markov Property. **In particular, I am trying to design a simulation to visualize the difference between the Strong Markov Property and the Weak Markov Property.**

In my question, I will first present my understanding of the Strong Markov Property vs the Weak Markov Property, and then present a simulation. Ideally, in the simulation, we should be able to see and compare the "strength" of both Markov properties.

**Part 1: Definitions** For a Stochastic Process $X_t$, we can write:

The **Weak Markov Property**

- 1st Order:
  $$P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i, X_{t-1} = i_{t-1}, ..., X_0 = i_0) = P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i)$$
- 2nd Order:
  $$P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i, X_{t-1} = i_{t-1}, ..., X_0 = i_0) = P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i, X_{t-1} = i_{t-1})$$
- 3rd Order:

$$P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i, X_{t-1} = i_{t-1}, X_{t-2} = i_{t-2}, ..., X_0 = i_0) = P(X_{t+1} = j | X_t = i, X_{t-1} = i_{t-1}, X_{t-2} = i_{t-2})$$

The **Strong Markov Property:**

- Define $T$ as a Random Variable with density $P(T)$. $T$ is the called the "Stopping Time"
- Then, for all $ k < T$ :

$$P(X_{T+t} = j | X_k = x_k, X_T = i) = P(X_{T+t} = j | X_T = i)$$

The Strong Markov Property tells us that the value of the process at time $T+t$  only depends on the value of the process at time $T$ .

Here is my understanding of the Strong Markov Property. Suppose the first 3 Stopping Times are T= 12, T= 21 and T = 27. The value of the process $X_t$ at t=18 would ONLY depend on the values of the process at t=12. And the value of the process at t=23 would ONLY depend on the values of the process at t=21.

**Part 2: Simulation**

I tried to think of an idea to illustrate the Weak Markov Property vs the Strong Markov Property. Suppose there is a 2 sided coin (0=heads, 1=tails) with transition probabilities $p_{0,0}, p_{0,1}, p_{1,0}, p_{1,1}$. Let's say that at first, the coin has a 0.5 probability of being either heads or tails.

- Weak Markov Property: After the first flip with (0.5,0.5) probability, the behavior of the coin will follow the transition probabilities
- Strong Markov Property: Suppose we have a vector of Stopping Times. If I understood this correctly, after each stopping time value, the Markov Chain will "restart" and the immediate next flip after the stopping time will be (0.5,0.5) regardless if there was a strong streak of heads right before.

Here is my attempt to simulate this (using the R programming language) - I made a coin that is highly likely to repeat the current result in the next flip. If I understand correctly, the Strong Markov Property should interrupt long streaks of the same result once a stopping time is reached (I chose 6 random stopping times) :

```
library(ggplot2)


# plot function
plot_chain <- function(chain, title, stopping_times = NULL) {
    df <- data.frame(Time = 1:length(chain), State = chain)
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = State)) +
        geom_line() +
        scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c("0", "1")) +
        labs(title = title, x = "Time", y = "State") +
        theme_bw()
    if (!is.null(stopping_times)) {
        for (t in stopping_times) {
            p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = t, linetype = "solid", color = "red", size = 1)
        }
    }
    return(p)
}

# Weak Markov Property (1st order)

n <- 100 # number of tosses
states <- c(0, 1) # 0 for heads, 1 for tails
transition_matrix <- matrix(c(0.99, 0.01, 0.01, 0.99), nrow=2, dimnames=list(states, states)) # transition probabilities
chain <- rep(NA, n)
chain[1] <- sample(states, 1, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)) # initial state

for (i in 2:n) {
    current_state <- chain[i-1]
    chain[i] <- sample(states, 1, prob=transition_matrix[current_state+1, ])
}

# Plot
p1 <- plot_chain(chain, "Weak Markov Property: First-Order Markov Chain")

# Strong Markov Property: Process with Stopping Times

n <- 100 # number of tosses
states <- c(0, 1) # 0 for heads, 1 for tails
transition_matrix <- matrix(c(0.99, 0.01, 0.01, 0.99), nrow=2, dimnames=list(states, states)) # transition probabilities
chain <- rep(NA, n)
chain[1] <- sample(states, 1, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)) # initial state
stopping_times <- sort(sample(1:n, 6)) # 6 random stopping times

for (i in 2:n) {
    if (i %in% stopping_times) {
        chain[i] <- sample(states, 1, prob=c(0.5, 0.5)) # restart the process at stopping times
    } else {
        current_state <- chain[i-1]
        chain[i] <- sample(states, 1, prob=transition_matrix[current_state+1, ])
    }
}

# Plot
p2 <- plot_chain(chain, "Strong Markov Property: Process with Stopping Times", stopping_times)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=1)
```

[image]

As we can see, in the Weak Markov Property, long streaks are seldom interrupted. Whereas in the Strong Markov Property, long streaks are interrupted more frequently around the stopping times (indicated in red).

Is my understanding of this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately your understanding of all of this is not correct!

As it happens, there are no examples in discrete time where the strong Markov property holds, but the Markov property does not. Any discrete-time Markov chain satisfies the strong Markov property. To find examples of processes which obey the Markov property but not the strong Markov property, you would have to move to continuous time. There is some discussion at [this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43833/a-markov-process-which-is-not-a-strong-markov-process).

To understand the strong Markov property you first have to understand what a stopping time is. A random variable $T$ taking values in non-negative integers is a stopping time for the process $X_0, X_1, X_2, \dots$ if, for any $n\geq 0$, the event $\{T=n\}$ depends only on $X_0, X_1, \dots, X_n$.

Then one version of the strong Markov property is as follows. Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a time-homogeneous Markov chain with transition matrix $P$. Let $T$ be a stopping time for the process. Then conditional on $T<\infty$ and $X_T=i$, the process $(X_{T+n})_{n\geq 0}$ is Markov with initial state $i$ and transition matrix $P$, and is independent of $(X_0, X_1, \dots, X_{T-1})$.

To get a feeling for this you maybe have to look at a few different basic texts and lots of examples -- particularly to get a good intuition for what a stopping time is. You could start for example with James Norris's notes at [https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/](https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejames/Markov/) , specifically Section 1.4.

Comment: @ James Martin: Thank you for your answer! If you have time, can you please help me think of a computer simulation I can use that visually demonstrates the difference between the Strong Markov Property and the Weak Markov Property? E.g. something like I have done (incorrectly), but for the continuous case? If you can help me think of the pseudocode, I can then try to write the actual code for this simulation. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm haven't understood what you want to achieve with such a simulation - sounds like you have a lot of more basic stuff to understand first! But for example one could simulate the process described in this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/182859/

Comment: you are right, I do have a lot of basic things to learn first! i actually have a learning disability and sometimes I find it challenging to understand things ... visual simulations often help me... I just wanted to see a stochastic process with the strong markov property .... and a similar stochastic process with the weak markov property.... and then this way (through visualization) I could kind of see how the presence/absence of strong vs weak markov property affects the behavior of the stochastic process. thank you so much!

Comment: stats_noob: Here's my elementary take on your question. Forget about the "weak" markov property assuming that you understand it !!!!! ( which is equivalent to understanding what a discrete markov chain is and I bet you understand that ). The strong markov property is an altogether different animal because it requires deep understanding of what a continuous time markov chain is. Yes, brownian motion is a ct mc but that's not where to start. The place to really start is to understand what it means for something to be a continuous time markov chain.

Comment: So, I would read this first. It's the best thing I've found as far as really understanding what it is. Of course,  there are many texts but it's been so long that I wouldn't even know what text to look at. and most of them are in storage anyway. Then, once you get through that and understand it in a pretty deep way, then maybe examples would help I found something that has examples but you could probably take it from there, once you understand link below. Note that this is my biased take on things and I'm NOT a math person. They may prefer other things.

Comment: https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/16%3A_Markov_Processes/16.15%3A_Introduction_to_Continuous-Time_Markov_Chains